# Change Django Radio input into toggle button using bootstrap switch or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

models.py

```
class Listener(models.Model):
    # other columns
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Initially I was planning on creating a AvailabilityForm object and take the input as RadioSelect widget. But I want to change the appearance of the radio button into a toggle switch. And I was thinking of using https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch but I am not sure how I can incorporate that using django templates. So here are my questions:
1) Can I extend the basic django widgets to get my desired effect (toggle switch) or would it be easier to write the html and get the input using request.GET? 
2) I want one of the choices selected (or checked if use checkboxes instead) already according to the value in the db. How would I go about doing this? (not confident w/ my js skills)

Thanks for all the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I check the website http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ I see the following:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

A little javascript and css that you should insert into your template. I would not recommend their setup, move the javascript files to the bottom of the page.

And for a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>
```

There's nothing special, your checkbox can be:

```
class ListenerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # other columns
    availability = forms.CheckboxInput()  # Or any other type of checkbox field
```

Render it in your template using `{{ form.as_p }}`

And last but not least:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

for the checkbox you want to show as the Bootstrap Switch